# dict.get returns empty instead of default value

Tags: python, dictionary

I got a CSV-file that contains the rows `id`, `name`, `firstname` and `company`

I'm looping over the CSV with `csv.DictReader` and want to insert some default-values into `name` and `firstname` if they are empty

`dict.get()` should do the trick - however it only works if `name` and `firstname` **never** contain any data. As soon as they contain data at least once, the returned default-value will be omited and *nothing* gets returned

## test.csv

```
"id","name","firstname","company"
"1","doe","john","jdoe inc"
"2","doe","jane","jdoe inc"
"3",,,"company inc"
```

## import_csv.py

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for row in reader:
        firstname = row.get("firstname", "Company")
        name = row.get("name", row["company"])
        company = row["company"]

        print(f"Firstname:  {firstname}")
        print(f"Name:       {name}")
        print(f"Company:    {company}\n")
```

---

The output of the above test-script is

```
Firstname:  john
Name:       doe
Company:    jdoe inc

Firstname:  jane
Name:       doe
Company:    jdoe inc

Firstname:
Name:
Company:    company inc
```

My desired output would be

```
Firstname:  john
Name:       doe
Company:    jdoe inc

Firstname:  jane
Name:       doe
Company:    jdoe inc

Firstname:  Company       # <- default value of dict.get()
Name:       company inc   # <- default value of dict.get()
Company:    company inc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dict.get()` returns the default value only if the key *is not set*. But `DictReader()` is setting the key, with an empty string as the value. That's because there is an empty string in that column.

In fact, `DictReader()` guarantees that the there is a key set for every field name (where the field names are taken from the first row here); if a column is missing entirely, the value is set to `None`.

You can trivially account for this by using [`or`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```
firstname = row["firstname"] or "Company"
name = row["name"] or row["company"]
```

There is no point in using `dict.get()` if a key is always there. But if `row["firstname"]` is set to either an empty string *or* `None`, then that's a value that is [considered false](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), and so Python will produce the other operand to `or` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much - that is exactly what I was looking for! Since _firstname_ is not always provided, I may want to stick with `dict.get()` but I'll defenitely use `or` for _name_ :)

Comment: @Razorfen: if your CSV file first line has a `firstname` column, then all dictionaries produced from that file will have a `firstname` key. The same if you set the `fieldnames` argument explicitly instead of having `DictReader()` use the first row.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately the CSV-file does not always contain `firstname` (didn't mention it, sorry for that)